# Change title based on presence of params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have a project for data storage records.

There is a nested resource, disks -> works.

I can then filter works index based the presence of params[:disk_id].

The h1 to the page is always "Works".
I want it to change to "Works in Disk x", if there is a params[:disk_id] present.

Haven't managed to get a simple DRY way to manage this. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use content_for construction in your layout to fill the title based on content (HAML syntax in example):

```
%title
  - unless content_for?(:title)
    Works
  - else
    = yield :title
```

And in your views you can define `content_for :title` as you wish:

```
- content_for :title do
  Works if Disk #{@disk.name}
```